# SSE ReactNative on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, server-sent-events

Is it possible to use SSE for Android devices in ReactNative?

I've been struggling a lot with SSE on Android devices using ReactNative lately, any library I tried failed to except any server sent events.

Every library opens connection well but does not except any events.

I guess it is related to the `xhr` because every library uses it.

Libraries I tried:

- [rn-event-source-reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-eventsource-reborn)
- [react-native-sse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-sse)
- [react-native-event-source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-event-source)
- [react-sse-hooks](https://github.com/NepeinAV/react-sse-hooks)
- [react-native-eventsource](https://github.com/JonnyBGod/react-native-eventsource)

Judging by this [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28835), I'm not the only one having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

React Native use Flipper to deals with Logs and Debugging. So, Flipper has a wrapper to handle Networking. The issue is that flipper handle streaming itself.
So you can comment the code of flipper:
Go to following file:

```
android/app/src/debug/java/com/yourProject/ReactNativeFlipper.java
```

and comment these lines:

```
NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
  NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
      new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
          builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin));
        }
      });
  client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
  client.start();
```

Or you can use Flipper App for watching streamed content.